# Clojure macro that will conserve associative map order

Tags: casting, macros, clojure, hashmap, associative-array

To preface, I am on Windows 7 (64-bit), running Java version 6 (update 33) using [clooj](https://github.com/arthuredelstein/clooj) as my IDE. I have not tried to reproduce my problem in any other system. I am experienced with Clojure, but not at all with Java.

The entirety of the problem I am trying to solve is lengthy to describe, but it boils down to this: let's say I would like to a make a macro that takes one argument, an associative map, and returns a vector of the elements of the map with their order conserved.

```
=>(defmacro vectorize-a-map
    [associative-map]
    (vec associative-map))
=>#'ns/vectorize-a-map
=>(vectorize-a-map {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d 4 :e 5 :f 6 :g 7 :h 8}
=>[[:a 1] [:b 2] [:c 3] [:d 4] [:e 5] [:f 6] [:g 7] [:h 8]]
```

That works, but add another element to the map and the order messes up...

```
=>(vectorize-a-map {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d 4 :e 5 :f 6 :g 7 :h 8 :i 9}
=>[[:a 1] [:c 3] [:b 2] [:f 6] [:g 7] [:d 4] [:e 5] [:i 9] [:h 8]]
```

I believe I have discovered why this is happening. It seems like anything with 8 or fewer elements is instantiated as a PersistentArrayMap, which is exactly what I want, because from what I can tell, this class retains order. However, anything with 9 or more elements is instantiated as a PersistentHashMap, which does not retain order.

```
=>(type {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d 4 :e 5 :f 6 :g 7 :h 8}
=>clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap
=>(type {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d 4 :e 5 :f 6 :g 7 :h 8 :i 9}
=>clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap
```

I would like my macro to be able to take associative maps of any size, so this is a problem. I have tried type hinting, destructuring binding, **for** list comprehension, and unquote splicing, all without success. To draw it out, none of the following will work:

```
(defmacro vectorize-a-map
  [^clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap associative-map]
  (vec associative-map))

(defmacro vectorize-a-map
  [[& associative-map]]
  (vec associative-map))

(defmacro vectorize-a-map
  [associative-map]
  (vec
    (for [x associative-map]
      x)))

(defmacro vectorize-a-map
  [associative-map]
  `(vector ~@associative-map))
```

With this toy problem I present, I realize I could simply write my macro like so, and avoid the problem altogether:

```
=>(defmacro vectorize-kvs
    [& elements]
    (vec (map vec (partition 2 elements))))
=>#'ns/vectorize-kvs
=>(vectorize-kvs :a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d 4 :e 5 :f 6 :g 7 :h 8 :i 9)
=>[[:a 1] [:b 2] [:c 3] [:d 4] [:e 5] [:f 6] [:g 7] [:h 8] [:i 9]]
```

However, for the *actual* problem I am trying to solve (which I have not gotten into), it is important (although not 100% necessary) that the macro be able to take associative maps. It seems like I'm looking for how to cast the argument into a PersistentArrayMap before anything has a chance to happen to it. There may be some other avenue to a solution that I am simply not considering or aware of.

I've researched the best I've known how and haven't found anything helpful yet. Does anybody have any thoughts/advice?

Comment: the first rule of macro club is "don't write a macro" ... (can you guess the second)

Comment: I imagine the second rule is: "Shut up. Seriously, don't write a macro."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can make your map with array-map

```
user> (map vec (array-map 1 2 3 4 5 6))
([1 2] [3 4] [5 6])
```

or with a larger map

```
user> (map vec (apply array-map (range 50)))
([0 1] [2 3] [4 5] [6 7] [8 9] [10 11] [12 13] [14 15] [16 17] [18 19] [20 21] [22 23] [24 25] [26 27] [28 29] [30 31] [32 33] [34 35] [36 37] [38 39] [40 41] [42 43] [44 45] [46 47] [48 49])
```

as a bonus you can avoid using a macro, which is useful because macros are not first-class and don't compose well*

---

a note on your first comment from the documentation on [array map](http://clojure.org/data_structures#Data%20Structures-ArrayMaps)

```
 Note that an array map will only maintain sort order when un-'modified'. 
 Subsequent assoc-ing will eventually cause it to 'become' a hash-map.
```

If you find yourself depending on the order of keys in your maps you may want to consider if a `sorted-map` will get you what you need. It will scale better than an `array-map`. In the above example the output is the same:

```
(map vec (apply sorted-map (range 5000)))
[0 1] [2 3] ... [4998 4999]
```

*this is my opinion

---

EDIT:

a time comparason of `sorted-map` vs. `array-map`

```
user> (time (dorun (map vec (apply sorted-map (range 500000)))))
"Elapsed time: 391.520491 msecs"
nil
user> (time (dorun (map vec (apply array-map (range 500000)))))
"Elapsed time: 674517.821669 msecs"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sadly, I must disobey the first rule of macro club because it is imperative for the "function" I make to receive non-evaluated code. I do not take macros lightly. I did already try out the array-map function (as well as sorted-map), but it didn't *really* solve my problem because then my literal code would look like (array-map :a 1 :b 2 ... etc.) instead of {:a 1 :b 2 ... etc.}. In fact, I *could* make that work, but then when I would go to use my macro, I could not necessarily use {} for maps, but may have to use (array-map etc.), and I would prefer to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem as stated is not soluble. Maps are defined to have no order; any order you see in `array-map` is coincidental. If you require that your macro receive a map, you have already lost the information you desire.

Comment: " it is often desirable to have a map which maintains key order. An array map is such a map" http://clojure.org/data_structures#Data%20Structures-ArrayMaps

Comment: I disagree both with the assertion that it's desirable, and with the implication that it is useful for code transformations. For example, `{25 (println 25), 26 (println 26), 27 (println 27), 28 (println 28), 29 (println 29), 30 (println 30), 31 (println 31), 32 (println 32), 33 (println 33), 34 (println 34)}` reads as a hash-map, and therefore prints in a different order than lexical; preserving the order of that is not possible so it shouldn't be relied on in any case.