# Convert a Clojure map into XML

Tags: xml, clojure

I am trying to find an easy solution to convert Clojure data structures to XML.

this [Clojure hash-map to xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729910/clojure-hash-map-to-xml) does not work.

I used

```
data.xml
```

can it create a solution for me?

Comment: It’s unclear what you have tried based on your question, so very hard to give constructive help. clojure.data.xml works, in my experience.

Comment: Please provide an example of your input data and the desired output, as well as what you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is just what you need:

```
(:require [clojure.data.xml :as xml])

  (xml/emit-str
   (xml/element
    :response {}
    (map (fn make-node [[f s]]
           (if (map? s)
             (xml/element f {} (map make-node (seq s)))
             (xml/element f {} s)))
         (seq --your-map--))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of using `clojure.data.xml`:

```
(ns tst.tupelo.parse.xml
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [clojure.data.xml :as clj-xml]))

(def enlive-tree-normalized-nonblank
  {:tag     :foo,
   :attrs   {},
   :content [{:tag :name, :attrs {}, :content ["John"]}
             {:tag :address, :attrs {}, :content ["1 hacker way"]}
             {:tag :phone, :attrs {}, :content []}
             {:tag     :school,
              :attrs   {},
              :content [{:tag :name, :attrs {}, :content ["Joe"]}
                        {:tag :state, :attrs {}, :content ["CA"]}
                        {:tag :type, :attrs {}, :content ["FOOBAR"]}]}
             {:tag     :college,
              :attrs   {},
              :content [{:tag :name, :attrs {}, :content ["mit"]}
                        {:tag :address, :attrs {}, :content []}
                        {:tag :state, :attrs {}, :content ["Denial"]}]}]})

(println (clj-xml/indent-str enlive-tree-normalized-nonblank))
```

with result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
  <name>John</name>
  <address>1 hacker way</address>
  <phone/>
  <school>
    <name>Joe</name>
    <state>CA</state>
    <type>FOOBAR</type>
  </school>
  <college>
    <name>mit</name>
    <address/>
    <state>Denial</state>
  </college>
</foo>
```

[Here are three examples](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/test/clj/tst/tupelo/parse/xml.clj#L118) of parsing XML into Clojure data structures (Enlive format) using `clojure.data.xml`, `tupelo.parse.xml`, and `tupelo.parse.tagsoup`.

Comment: I have been experimenting with the clojure.data.xml library in a Clojurescript project. It seems that some of the functions work, some do not in cljs. For example emit-str seems to work but indent-str does not - I. get the following error: _Use of undeclared Var clojure.data.xml/indent-str_